# Why is a simple SQL script so much slower in Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I run a simple insert/update/delete 1m rows script to crudely check the health of our SQL server installations. It's 10 times slower in Azure SQL(S6) than on our in-house test server. Anyone experienced similar problems? Is there a fundamental difference in the way that Azure SQL behaves which invalidates the test?

**Test Results**

*Our Internal Server*

32GB RAM, Intel Xenon 3.3 Ghz
(1000000 rows affected)

Insert Duration = **124**  Seconds

Update Duration = 3  Seconds

Delete Duration = 3  Seconds

*Azure SQL database 400 DTUs (S6)*
(1000000 rows affected)

Insert Duration = **1267** Seconds

Update Duration = 36 Seconds

Delete Duration = 71 Seconds

**SQL Server Script**

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'PerfTest') >0
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE PerfTest
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PerfTest](
        [PerfID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [PerfTX] [varchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL,
        [PerfDT] [datetime] NULL,
        [PerfNm] [int] NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_PerfTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        ([PerfID] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PerfTest](
        [PerfID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [PerfTX] [varchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL,
        [PerfDT] [datetime] NULL,
        [PerfNm] [int] NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_PerfTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        ([PerfID] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
    END

DECLARE
      @InsertStart DATETIME,
      @InsertEnd DATETIME,
      @DeleteStart DATETIME,
      @DeleteEnd DATETIME,
      @UpdateStart DATETIME,
      @UpdateEnd DATETIME,
      @PID AS INT,
      @PTX AS VARCHAR(20),
      @PDT AS DATETIME,
      @PNM AS INT

BEGIN
    PRINT 'Timings will be at the bottom of this result set'
    SET @PID = 0
    SET @PNM = 0
    SET @PTX = 'ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ'
    SET @InsertStart = GETDATE()

    --Insert Test
    WHILE (@PID < 1000000)
    BEGIN
        SET @PID = @PID + 1
        SET @PNM = @PNM + 1
        SET @PDT = GETDATE()
        INSERT INTO PerfTest VALUES(@PID, @PTX, @PDT, @PNM)
    END
    SET @InsertEnd = GETDATE()

    --Begin Update Test
    SET @UpdateStart = GETDATE()
    UPDATE PerfTest SET PerfNm = PerfNm + 1
    SET @UpdateEnd = GETDATE()
    --Begin Delete Test
    SET @DeleteStart = GETDATE()
    DELETE FROM PerfTest
    SET @DeleteEnd = GETDATE()
    PRINT 'Insert Duration = ' ++ CAST(DATEDIFF(SS,@InsertStart, @InsertEnd) AS CHAR(5)) ++ ' Seconds'
    PRINT 'Update Duration = ' ++ CAST(DATEDIFF(SS,@UpdateStart, @UpdateEnd) AS CHAR(5)) ++ ' Seconds'
    PRINT 'Delete Duration = ' ++ CAST(DATEDIFF(SS,@DeleteStart, @DeleteEnd) AS CHAR(5)) ++ ' Seconds'
    DROP TABLE PerfTest
END
```

Thanks people, I'd really appreciate you sharing any experience you have in this area

Comment: Is your server configured for transactional replication or even file system snapshots? Apart from that, S6 is CPU-optimized while your benchmark counts IO performance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting 1000 rows into Azure Database takes 13 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573010/inserting-1000-rows-into-azure-database-takes-13-seconds) Your tests are almost identical to this thread and I think the answers will be nearly the same. At minimum, the debugging will be the same (try a single transaction, look at the wait stats, etc.)

Comment: Worth noting that we are testing an s6 400 dtu server, which is why I think this q isn't a duplicate. The 1000 row question used a standard S0 tier. Thanks for your input, people

Comment: How did you collect your stats?

Comment: The statistics are written out by the sql script, it stores start time and compares with end time